# Wordpress category order by custom field(done). How to output custom field only once

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I create a catalog of companies by cities using the Wordpress categories.
Categories are cities.
Custom field is a region in which cities are included.
For custom field used - [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)
For build custom taxanomy order used - [WP Term Order](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-order/)

```
$terms = get_terms( 'catalog_categories', array(
    'depth'      => 1,
    'number'     => 100,
    'parent'     => 0,
    'orderby'    => 'taxon_name', // order array name
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'taxon_name' => array(
            'key' => 'taxon' // acf custom field name
        ) )
) );

foreach ($terms as $key => $object) {
    $region = get_field('taxon', $object);
    echo $region . ' ' . $object->name . '<br>';
}
```

I recive:
**Wielkopolskie** Poznań
**Wielkopolskie** Bojanowo
**Mazoweckie** Warszawa
**Dolnoslaskie** Wrocław
**Dolnoslaskie** Jawor

But i need:
**Wielkopolskie**
-- Poznań
-- Bojanowo
**Mazoweckie**
-- Warszawa
**Dolnoslaskie**
-- Wrocław
-- Jawor

*Help please with the decision of this problem*

**UPDATE**
*Help please add a link (slug) to the Wordpress category to the code
Here we collect all the cities of one region:
**$collection[$region][] = $object->name;**
We need to add to each city a slug
**$object->slug;**
The slug we need to use it as value for option.

```
'<option value="' . **SLUG** . '" data-select2-id="'. $data_select_id . '-' .$i .'">' . $city . '</option>';
```

**UPDATE**:
*Working code
We added to - $collection[$region][] = $object->name; - $object->slug and combined them into an array
$collection[$region][] = array('name' => $object->name, 'slug' => $object->slug);
And for the output we use - $city['name'] and $city['slug']

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'catalog_categories', array(
    'depth'      => 1,
    'number'     => 100,
    'parent'     => 0,
    'orderby'    => 'taxon_name', // order array name
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'taxon_name' => array(
            'key' => 'taxon' // acf custom field name
        ) )
) );

$collection = [];
foreach ($terms as $key => $object) {
    $region = get_field('taxon', $object);

    if (!isset($collection[$region])) {
        $collection[$region] = [];
    }

    $collection[$region][] = array('name' => $object->name, 'slug' => $object->slug);
}

$data_select_id = 1;
echo '<div>';
    foreach ($collection as $region => $cities) {

        $i = 0;

        echo '<div label="' . $region . '" data-select2-id="' . $data_select_id . '">'. $region;
            foreach ($cities as $city) {
                $i++;
                echo '<option value="' . $city['slug'] . '" data-select2-id="'. $data_select_id . '-' .$i .'">' . $city['name'] . '</option>';
            }
        echo '</div>'; 

        $data_select_id ++;

    }
echo '</div>'; 
;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an additional array to sort out cities into regions like this:

```
$collection = [];
foreach ($terms as $key => $object) {
    $region = get_field('taxon', $object);

    if (!isset($collection[$region])) {
        $collection[$region] = [];
    }

    $collection[$region][] = $object->name;
}

foreach ($collection as $region => $cities) {
    echo $region . '<br/>';
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        echo '--' . $city . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, now I will check everything and write the result.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works exactly the way I need it!

Comment: Thank you. Tell me please, how can I add more $object->slug, for each $city, to use it as a url to a each category.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that. What do you mean by “more $object->slug”?

Comment: Wielkopolskie //region ACF custom field<br>
-- Poznań //city wordpress category, i need category slug - "poznan" to add link to city name <a href="$object->slug">$object->name</a> <br>
-- Bojanowo<br>
Mazoweckie<br>
-- Warszawa<br>
Dolnoslaskie<br>
-- Wrocław<br>
-- Jawor<br>

Comment: [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#return) returns a list of [WP_Term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects. These are your cities as `$object`. So you can use `$object->slug` directly.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, could not properly explain the task, I did it all. Thank you for your help.